# IntelliJ PlantUML plugin does not detect *.pu files

Tags: intellij-idea, plantuml

I installed the [PlantUML plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration/) in IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2. I have a repo with a bunch of *.pu files, but these are not being rendered. However if I change the file extension to *.puml it works. Is there a way to configure the plugin so that it can read *.pu files as well?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you submit this to the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/esteinberg/plantuml4idea/issues) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `*.pu` into the list of the PlantUML Diagram extensions at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | File Types:

[image: File Types]